# Xcode working with two Projects in Split View

Tags: xcode, workflow, macos-catalina, splitview

Seems that Xcode 11.2.1 still does not allow having **two project** windows side by side in **split view** (like Safari e.g.). Translation for the lower right: *Not available in this split view* (which is actually the second project window). I even tried to hide the Navigator and Inspector panes in both projects with a symmetrical split view. Am I missing something?

Running Catalina 10.15.1.
[image: Screenshot of two open projects - trying to show side-by-side]